# Visual Studio Publish Azure Container App missing

Tags: azure, docker, visual-studio, visual-studio-2022, azure-container-instances

I have a NET 7 Console App and trying to publish docker container to Azure in Visual Studio 2022 following this guide (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-apps/deploy-visual-studio).

For some reason I am unable to see all the Azure Publishing Target options. I only see the following:

[image]

Compared the following options in the MS guide:

[image]

My Visual Studio info:

```
Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2022
Version 17.7.5
VisualStudio.17.Release/17.7.5+34202.233
Microsoft .NET Framework
Version 4.8.09032
```

I have confirmed and tried the following:

- Confirmed Azure Service Authentication account is logged in.
- Project Target Framework = net7.0
- Project Docker Default Target OS = Linux
- Installed VS Azure Development workload
- Confirmed Docker container builds fine and runs fine in Docker Desktop locally

Any ideas why the Azure Container target (and so many others) is missing for me?

Comment: Or perhaps the process has just changed? From the Azure Portal I did find a way to spin up a new Web App using Docker Container and tie that to my published Azure Container Registry. Is that the workflow now? Tutorials get outdated so quickly and find Azure rather unintuitive.

Comment: @seancro If you are trying with the console app, you didn't find the options in it. Those options are available in the ASP.NET Core Web App only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying with the console app, the option won’t be visible. Those options are available in the [ASP.NET](http://ASP.NET) Core Web App only.

I followed the same [MS Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-apps/deploy-visual-studio) and was able to see the options and publish.

I created an **ASP. NET Core Web App** with **.net 7 version**. Click on **Enable Docker** option and clicked on create as below:

[image]

Then, I started publishing the application as below:-

[image]

[image]

I created a container app as shown below,

[image]

[image]

[image]

Next, I created a Registry like below,

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Then, I clicked on Publish as shown below:

[image]

The app was published successfully as below:-

[image]

The below output URL opens in the browser.

[image]

Then, I refreshed the browser and got the below output:-

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer and detailed explanation!